# Why does my loop export only one integer in the string?

Tags: loops, iteration, ascii

I am trying to Save each integer in string.ascii_uppercase as an image file.
The loop only saves one image (the letter Z), and does save or export the remaining characters A through Y.

Can someone please help me understand why?

```
characters = string.ascii_uppercase
filename = savepath+str(i)+'.png' #outputs as 'C:Users/X/X/X/Z.png'


for i in characters:
    #Settings
    W, H = (100, 100)
    #Image
    image = Image.new("RGB", (W, H), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    offset_w, offset_h = font.getoffset(i)
    w, h = draw.textsize(i, font=font)
    pos = ((W-w-offset_w)/2, (H-h-offset_h)/2)
    #Draw
    draw.text(pos, i, "green", font=font)
    #Save PNG File
    image.save(filename, "PNG", quality = 95)
```

My guess is that it is looping through all integers but only saving the final integer, instead of saving each individual integer.

Comment: Should the filename string be inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes, because each i in the string (aka letter A through Z)  needs to be saved as an individual .png file.

Comment: Makes sense, so why is it assigned outside?

Comment: Sorry I am newer to Python .. is it outside the loop? I defined it outside the loop, but the final line of code is supposed to be inside the loop.

Comment: Move filename=... to the line after #Save PNG File